# Target link by attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to activate a link via javascript which looks like this:

```
<a class="second_link nobold" data-type="via_mail" href="http://swap.mtr.com/index.php?id=10&ctid=546432#">Send via mail</a>
```

I thought about targeting the link via `class`, but there are numerous links with that class.
 How do I activate the link through `data-type="via_mail"`?

Comment: Can you use jQuery? vanilla js code is way to long...

Comment: Sorry @gdoron, no I cannot

Comment: Then use the vanilla js code in my answer.

Comment: Don't upvote all the answer just to be nice, though being nice is ummm... nice, if you upvote all the answers even the bad ones, it ruins SO. (if it was you who upvoted all the answers).

Comment: Sorry, it _was_ me who upvoted all the answers. I'll refrain from doing so next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you target only modern browser you can use `document.querySelector`

```
document.querySelector('a.second_link[data-type="via_mail"]').click();
```

If you can use jQuery:

```
$('.second_link[data-type="via_mail"]').click();
```

If non of the above helps, you need to write some more...

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++)
    if (ele[i].getAttribute('data-type') == 'via_mail')
        ele[i].click();
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fz4xb/)

Comment: Thanks that was great! I had to use the second version as the first one only worked in FF and I have to use IE.

Comment: I meant third version, not second ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what browsers you plan on supporting you can do `querySelectorAll` with most modern browsers:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[data-type='via_mail']");
```

Answer (score 1):

As showed by others, if use / can use jQuery, you can simple have:

```
var link = $("a[data-type='via_mail']")[0];
```

However, if the browser you're going to support implements `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll`, you can simply have:

```
var link = document.querySelector("a[data-type='via_mail']");
```

Without additional library.

Answer (score 0):

this javascript should work in every browser:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i=0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    if (anchors[i].getAttribute("data-type") == "via_mail") {
        // GOTCHA!
    }
}
```

if you can use jQuery attribute selector:

```
$('a[data-type="via_mail"]');
```

Comment: You *just* beat me to it :)

Comment: Hi Tsar, thanks but I cannot use jquery :). This is for a macro tool and I activate the javascript by entering it into the address bar of a non-jquery page.

Comment: Do you know **you're selecting the DOM n+1 times instead of just once** ?! -1